# What was Takhisis' plan for Berem, why did his death closed the portal instead of opening it?

Tags: dragonlance

Why was the portal ultimately closed when Berem died on the foundation stone instead of opening it for Takhisis?

Early on the lore when Jasla dies, there is "a chain forged of love" effect that bars Takhisis from using the gate, but when Berem dies in Spring Dawning and he and Jasla are freed, why does the portal closes and the whole temple crumbles? Shouldn't the portal then become open and unobstructed?

Was it because the emerald was destroyed and it was an inherent part of the portal? In that case, why did Takhisis give it to Berem, did she not know yet it would be necessary?

I wonder what was her plan then, to capture him and first remove the gem to get rid of his gift of immortality, be able to kill him so he would take Jasla away from the foundation stone as their spirits go forth into the next plane, and then have the portal unobstructed so she could cross it? But that was basically what happened if not by the completely accidental destruction of the emerald.

I plan to have a chance of my players to actually fail that part, have Takhisis enter Krynn and continue forth from there, but how could she had succeed then? What went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very similar to this one. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166760/was-the-foundation-stone-an-open-portal-by-design-or-did-berem-open-it

Answer (score 5):

Here is something interesting I found. In the original [DRAGONS OF TRUTH (ADVANCED DUNGEONS & DRAGONS DRAGONLANCE MODULE DL13)](https://epdf.pub/dragons-of-truth-advanced-dungeons-amp-dragons-dragonlance-module-dl13.html), the one that had Berem's mission to return to the temple.
There are 6 different endings. Here is #5.

> 5. Berem and His Sister: **This is the end of the  story  given  in  the  novels.**  In  this  version, Berem Everman  takes  the  green  gemstone down  into  the  depths  of  the  temple  of  Takhisis and  replaces  it  into  the  foundation  stone.  This reunites  his  soul  with  that  of  his  sister  and makes  the  temple  once  more  a  holy  place. Through  this  act,  the  gate  through  which  the Queen  of  Darkness  came  is  shut  forever  and her  influence  much  diminished  in  the  world. The  Dragonarmies  turn  on  one  another  and disperse  to  strongholds  scattered  across Krynn. To  succeed,  Berem  Everman  must  be brought  to  the  foundation  stone  in  the  depths of  the  temple  and  press  his  bare  chest  and  its gem  into  the  stone. -  pg.3

When you look at scenario #6

> 6. Death  of  the  Gem:  Contrary  to  the  the version  in  the  books,  placing  the  gem  in  the foundation  stone  does  not  seal  the  gate. Rather,  it  permanently  opens  the  gate.  It  is  for this  reason  that  the  Queen  of  Darkness  has been  looking  for  the  green  gemstone  man. To succeed, the PCs must discover the gem’s true  purpose  and  destroy  it.  To  do  this,  the PCs  must  bring  Berem  to  the  Hidden  Treasury and  break  the  gem  with  the  stones  there. -pg. 3

**So it is possible that Takhisis thought scenario 6 was going to play out, when actually scenario 5 happened.** The Gods of Krynn seem to be a lot less omnipotent than in other realms.

I also found this [timeline](http://www.eclecticmayhem.com/dragonlance/history/despair.htm), which has no references (dates suggest 2003, it is possible someone was trying to build a custom Dragonlance campaign), but nevertheless has a chronology around the Foundation Stone.

- 3-140 AC: Takhisis finds the Temple of the Kingpriest of Istar in the Abyss.
- 141 AC: The Foundation Stone of the Temple of Istar is planted outside of Neraka, where it eventually forms the Temple, perverted by evil.
- 142-152 AC: The chromatic dragons of Takhisis awaken.
- 157 AC: Berem finds the stone
- 210 AC: Takhisis can no longer use the Foundation Stone as a gate into the world, as it is incomplete. She becomes aware of Berem.

That last entry suggests that Takhisis didn't use the gate very often, and it wasn't until long after she had amusingly cursed Berem with the stone in his chest that she realized something was wrong. So her pursuit of him wasn't to close the portal, but to try and restore it back to the way it was before his interference.

However, the similar question [Was the foundation stone an open portal by design, or did Berem open it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166760/was-the-foundation-stone-an-open-portal-by-design-or-did-berem-open-it), has an answer with contradictory statements between different novels.